# Certbot unable to locate environment variable credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server on an AWS EC2 instance running Apache and I'm trying to obtain a certificate using certbot, however I'm having trouble with credentials. Below is the command I run, followed by the error output:

```
user@address:~$ sudo certbot certonly --dns-route53 --dns-route53-propagation-seconds 30 -d mydomain.com -d *.mydomain.com -i apache

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-route53, Installer apache
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for mydomain.com
dns-01 challenge for mydomain.com
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to locate credentials
To use certbot-dns-route53, configure credentials as described at https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#best-practices-for-configuring-credentials and add the necessary permissions for Route53 access.
```

I've followed the below guides:

1. https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-apache.html (wildcard tab, up to step 6)
2. https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ (created an IAM policy and applied it to a new user)

and chosen to set the credentials using environment variables:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<id>
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret>
```

When I use `$ printenv AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$ printenv AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` I am shown the credentials on screen, so I don't understand why certbot is unable to locate them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By running the certbot command as `sudo` the environment variable is not set anymore.

Either connect to `sudo su` then export the variables and run or take a look at using a credentials file to allow the command access to the IAM key and IAM secret.

More information available [here](https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: I opted for the config file option, and after about an hour of further Linux-based mucking about I was able to install the certificates, many thanks!

Comment: Hey Tom I am running into this same issue. But certbot wont read my config/credentials files nor the env vars. Where did you create the config file

Comment: @Chris Williams - none of the two options you suggested are working in my case. I created the env vars in both root and home directory as well as using the credentials file.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `sudo` to execute your command, as you supplied above (and here it is again for reference):

```
sudo certbot certonly --dns-route53 --dns-route53-propagation-seconds 30 -d mydomain.com -d *.mydomain.com -i apache
```

Then the environment variables and home directory of the user **root** are used, instead of those of the current logged on user. So, you have to ensure that your setup is for the root user.

In my case, I prefer to use a config file instead of environment variables. And because of `sudo`, this config file path and name is *~/.aws/config* and its content is:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<YOUR ACCESS KEY TO AWS>
aws_secret_access_key=<YOUR SECRET ACCESS KEY TO AWS>
```

More details [here](https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Now, the root home directory in Linux will most probably be */root*, so this is where I would start. Details [here](https://appuals.com/fix-root-users-home-directory-root/).